# CodeIgniter - Write file names to database from multiple images

Tags: codeigniter

I have an upload form with two file upload fields. I am trying to upload the files, and then write the file names to the same row in a database. I have everything working except the file names get written to their own row. I am guessing it's because I am making two separate calls to the model, but I am not sure how to go about doing it in one call since they each have their own "if" statement.

To make my question clear. How do I write the names of two uploaded files to the same row in the database?

Any ideas would be great. This is the code I am working with. Thanks.

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload_controller');  ?>
<p>
    <input type="file" name="userfile">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="file" name="userfile1">
</p>
<p><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Upload them files!') ?></p>
<?php form_close() ?>
```

**Controller:**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $this->load->library('upload');

    if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        // Upload file 1
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $img = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $img['file_name'];

            $this->load->model('upload_file', 'upload_model');
            $this->upload_model->upload_file1($file_name);
        }
    }

    if (!empty($_FILES['userfile1']['name'])) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        // Upload file 2
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile1')) {
            $img = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $img['file_name'];

            $this->load->model('upload_file', 'upload_model');
            $this->upload_model->upload_file2($file_name);
        } else {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }
} else {
    $this->load->view("upload_form");
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function upload_file1($file_name) {

    $data = array('file1' => $file_name);
    $this->db->insert('images_table', $data);
}

public function upload_file2($file_name) {

    $data = array('file2' => $file_name);
    $this->db->insert('images_table', $data);
}
```

**Database row:**

```
| id | file1 | file2 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this(if you have the number of files....in your case it is "2" )

```
$this->load->model('upload_file', 'upload_model');
for($i=1;$i<=$numimg;$i++)                       //in your case $numimg = 2;
{
    if($this->upload->do_upload('File'.$i))      //File1,File2 are filenames
    {
       $img_data = $this->upload->data();
       $images[$i] = $img_data['file_name'];         
    }
 }
 $data['Image'] = implode(',',$images);
 $this->upload_model->upload_file($data);
```

at your model:

```
public function upload_file2($data)
{
    $data = array('file_name' => $data['Image']);
    $this->db->insert('images_table', $data);
}
```

That's it.If you want to retrive it from database use

```
$images = explode(',',$data->file_name);
```

it will give you an array of image names.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will be posting a similar question soon but adding text fields in the form and with fields names that are not as convenient.. just to extend my own knowledge.

Comment: If you have time, I would really appreciate you having a look at [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199938/codeigniter-write-text-and-file-fields-from-form-to-same-row-in-database)

Comment: Please stop asking people to accept your answers. If they are good and helpful, this will happen automatically.